# Laravel - Using Gate::allows for multiple objects

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

Is there a way to validate a policy for multiple elements or ids?

Let's say I have a `$user` object.

I can do: `\Gate::allows('delete', $user)`.

What if I have a collection of `User` objects: `$users`.

Is there a way to do `\Gate::allows('delete', $users)`?

EDIT:

I have a route for deleting multiple entities.

`Route::delete('/users', 'UsersController@deleteMultiple');`

The payload is an array of `ids`.

`['ids' => [1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: Are you able to use a loop?

Comment: Yes. I guess I can do that. The thing is that I have a route for deleting multiples resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a Gate in Laravel, you can pass any number of arguments to the closure. The only requirement is that the first parameter accepts a `$user` argument, which is the currently authenticated user. Any additional parameters you define are completely up to you. You could easily write a Gate that authorizes bulk delete functionality like this:

```
Gate::define('bulk-delete', function ($user, Collection $users) {
    // Your logic may differ
    return $users->every(function ($subject) use ($user) {
        return $user->canDelete($subject);
    });
});
```

Then, in your controller or service class, you can write the following:

```
if (Gate::allows('bulk-delete', $users)) {
    // The current user can bulk delete the users...
}
```

Of course, you will probably want to refactor this to a [Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#creating-policies) class for better maintainability.